# href and src attributes in .ejs template cannot be found

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

When I render my .ejs file the href and the src attributes are not referencing my local files. I am using node.js and express.

Here is the relevant part of the .ejs template.

```
 <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='../public/stylesheets/styles.css' />
           <script src="../us-map-1.0.1/lib/raphael.js"></script>
        <!-- <script src="scale.raphael.js"></script> -->
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="../us-map-1.0.1/color.jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="../us-map-1.0.1/jquery.usmap.js"></script>
        <script>
    </head>
```

This is router that renders the template

```
router.get('/submit', function(req, res, next) {...});
```

And this is what a typical query looks like

> http://localhost:3000/submit?leftHashtag=dog&rightHashtag=cat

Any help on why this is happening would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How did you configured static content serving?

Comment: I wasn't .I just looked up what that was and not having static content serving was my problem. Thanks so much for your help

Comment: You can answer and accept your own question to help future visitors with similar problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I wasn't defining my static content serving.

To fix this I added an `app.use` statement to my app.js file

```
app.use('/submit', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

So now any routes that begin with `/submit` will use this directory local to the app

```
__dirname/public
```

With `__dirname` being the current directory the app.js file is located in

If you would like to know more this blog goes into more detail about what is happening

http://blog.modulus.io/nodejs-and-express-static-content